# Wireguard connected but no internet acces

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, wireguard

My peer connects to my server but my peer has no internet acces and my server does.

My wg0.conf file

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.0.81/24
ListenPort = 41194
PrivateKey = MY_KEY
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o NIC1bond -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o NIC1bond -j MASQUERADE

[peer]
PublicKey = MY_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.102/32

[peer]
PublicKey = MY_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.178/32
```

Output

```
interface: wg0
  public key: oZyGGSJMOWVHEBgh65aQJgVXy7lccabOD97rO06pJTA=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 41194

peer: LEiIVzxbHQFKLZkS7WcVPS+As//CXrbBBPpYJUVH2Cc=
  endpoint: 192.168.0.102:41194
  allowed ips: 192.168.0.102/32
  latest handshake: 16 minutes, 46 seconds ago
  transfer: 84.96 KiB received, 1.14 KiB sent

peer: dgCw/u6UcB0jL3zeV7h1tWRP+YcLqkj6PV9fBr/8pEs=
  allowed ips: 192.168.0.178/32
```

So you see the transfer so it is connected but there is no internet acces on my peer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be missing

We enable forwarding:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

We add the rules of the firewall, essential to have Internet access from the server:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.102/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.102/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```